# Installer misses a step and won't let me mount partition while installing ubuntu budgie 18.04.3

Tags: system-installation, dell, inspiron, budgie

I am trying to install Budgie 18.04.3 64bit on a new Dell inspiron 5000, which has Windows 10 installed on its one drive.

I made a bootable USB drive with Rufus (tried both FAT32 and NTFS) then tried to install it. Before launching the installer it gave me the ACPI error which I have mentioned in this post.

So I ignored the error and continue with the installation. Got all the usual steps in the install wizard like set the language, keyboard etc. After selecting the Normal Install option the installer goes directly to this step, skipping the one where you select “Alongside another OS” or “Erase and install Ubuntu”

[image: installation type image link]

If I click install now it gives me “no root file system defined” error

If I click on the “Change” or “+” buttons then the installer hangs and freezes

How do I fix this? A friend of mine has also installed Budgie on their Dell laptop but they never encountered this problem.

[image: no root sys defined image link]
Some BIOS config

my fast boot mode is thorough
boot mode is UEFI only with secure boot enabled in deployed mode.

my boot sequence is

- Windows Boot Manager
- UEFI Hard Drive

Should I turn off secure boot? A friend suggested that but I would like to know why should I do it?

Should I turn the SATA operation to AHCI from RAID?

UPDATE:
I turned off secure boot and tried to install again again. I clicked on the change option on the installation type screen but the installer vanished.

THe same thing happened when clicked on "+" option.

Update2:

I tried the same bootable usb on an old lenovo laptop and I saw the "erase and install" and "alongside" options.

why am I not seeing this on the dell laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this was solved after doing two things:
 - My bootable usb was somehow corrupt (which is strange because when I did "check the disk for errors" none showed up). I used rufus to flash the image the first time but when I did it with [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) it was able to detect my SSD as a device but as a normal hard disk not an nvme drive
 - To solve the nvme drive problem, I went into my bios settings and changed SATA operator from RAID to AHCI and after applying those changes I was able to see the missing step in the installer and my SSD was detected as an nvme drive.

So in case of a new Dell laptop you might want to change your SATA operator (if you are doing a single boot I am not sure if windows would work after switching from RAID to AHCI) and then continue with the installation