# install Ubuntu 18.4 on Dell 13 7386

Tags: system-installation, windows, dell, live-usb, bios

I have a Dell 13 7000 (7386) which is running Windows 10 and I would like to replace it with Ubuntu 18.4 (just Ubuntu, no dual boot).

I created a bootable USB to test it and everything looks fine, but I have problems when I try to actually install it (following [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) guide): instead of getting to the "Allocate drive space" step, I get to a step in which I have to select the device/partition where to install it, but I can only select what looks like the USB drive itself.

I googled around and it found something that looked like a solution (e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350), [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/it/it/itdhs1/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en)) but it didn't actually work: after changing the BIOS "Sata Operation" from "RAID On" to "AHCI" I couldn't even start the laptop, so I had to switch back.

Has anyone found a working solution for a system like mine? Is there a reliable step-by-step guide?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to have AHCI on. If still Windows installed, you need Windows fast start up off. Dell similar across many models: Dell 7791 UEFI update & some settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2431450&page=3
Ubuntu 19.10 Provides Good Out-Of-The-Box Support For The Dell XPS 7390 Icelake Laptop
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps7390-ubuntu1910&num=1
 & Dell XPS 15 Series 7590 (2019)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161456/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-new-dell-xps-15-7000-series-7590 & 
https://github.com/TillmannBerg/Ubuntu-Dell-XPS-15-2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved combining all the pieces from the links I posted in the questions and others (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197440/installer-misses-a-step-and-wont-let-me-mount-partition-while-installing-ubuntu?rq=1) and the comment from @oldfred)

In particular I had to:
1) disable fast start up from the Control Panel ([here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001762.htm))
2) enter the BIOS settings and change the "SATA Operations" from "RAID On" to "AHCI"

Windows was indeed unable to boot, but I could boot Ubuntu live from the USB drive by pressing F12 at the startup (which didn't work before step 1, as I could only boot it from inside Windows)

The above made it possible to install Ubuntu the right way, i.e. I had access to the hard drive in order to overwrite it when installing.

Comment: Thanks to you, installation took me 15 min on my Dell :)